# Why UILongPressGestureRecognizer work in iOS simulator but not work for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, button, simulator

I am trying to add gesture into my Delete Button in a custom keyboard to ensure when it get long pressed system will work as System Delete Button which continuously execute proxy.deleteBackward() to delete.

Below is added:

```
var deleteButtonTimer: NSTimer?

let deleteButtonLongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPressForDeleteButtonWithGestureRecognizer:")
deleteButton.addGestureRecognizer(deleteButtonLongPressGestureRecognizer)
```

and then:

```
func handleLongPressForDeleteButtonWithGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .Began:
        print("long press confirmed")
        if deleteButtonTimer == nil {
            deleteButtonTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: "handleDeleteButtonTimerTick:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            deleteButtonTimer!.tolerance = 0.01
            NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(deleteButtonTimer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        }
    default:
        print("timer not added as expected")
        deleteButtonTimer?.invalidate()
        deleteButtonTimer = nil
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in iOS simulator: when long press the Delete Button "long press confirmed" get printed once only and the code addTimer() get executed and deletion continously executed as expected. But when I run in iPhone, system print "long press confirmed" once and then continuously print "timer not added as expected". It seems   NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(deleteButtonTimer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode) is not executed.

Why UILongPressGestureRecognizer work in iOS simulator but not work for iPhone.

BTW I am using Xcode 7.2 and iPhone6S iOS9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `gestureRecognizer.state` when you fall into the `default` case?

Most likely, on the phone, your finger is moving slightly, causing the gesture recognizer to change to state `UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed`. You don't want to invalidate your timer when that happens.

Comment: Hi Kurt, you are correct that the `gestureRecognizer.state` is 'Changed'. I added some code for `case .Changed:` and now it works. It's strange that the state becomes Changed as I don't think my finger moved :) But thanks to your reply I can work with it now.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to touch the iPhone screen and not move your finger slightly in the process. You can check `[gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:yourView]` to see how it changes.